# How to extract the SecretKey entries through OpenSSL command from a PKCS12 keystore file

Tags: secret-key, pkcs#12

How to extract the Secret Key entries through OpenSSL command from a PKCS12 keystore file

Answer (score 0):

openssl cannot do it. It does not implement processing the `secretBag` structure inside the PKCS#12 where secret keys are stored.

See also this excellent article, chapter PKCS#12. [Java KeyStores – the gory details](https://neilmadden.blog/2017/11/17/java-keystores-the-gory-details/), Neil Madden, 2017